# Remove certain characters from string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string that contains the following characters:
`\`, `/`, `*`, `[`, `]`, `:` and `?`

For example, I have string variable as

```
 sample_string = "/\\sdfs s*[]: asdf?"
```

I want to remove the above mentioned characters from `sample_string`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sample_string.tr("/*[]:?\\", "")
# => " dfs s asdf"
```

Comment: In the string I get this character \.

Comment: I had to do it like this        sample_string = sample_string.tr("\\", "") and then 
      sample_string = sample_string.tr("/*[]:?", ""). For some reason, if I do it in single line I get this character "/" always in the string.

Comment: Try `tr("/*[]:?\\", "")` instead. Check the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-tr) for details.

Comment: @sawa The the backslash must be placed at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String#delete!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-delete). To backslash character `\` has special meaning and must appear at the end.

```
sample_string = '/\\sdfs s*[]: asdf?'

sample_string.delete! '/*[]:?\\'

sample_string #=> "sdfs s asdf"
```